# QText Edit scroll bar

Tags: c++, qt

Does QTextedit have a scrollbar signals?

Answer (score 1):

`QTextEdit` inherits from `QAbstractScrollArea`, i.e. you could call e.g. `verticalScrollBar()` and then access signals `QScrollBar` inherits from `QAbstractSlider`.

But perhaps you could give more context what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. Scrolling is being signaled using events.
Take a look at
[`void QAbstractScrollArea::scrollContentsBy (int dx, int dy)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractscrollarea.html#scrollContentsBy)

Comment: Is there any way to related them. I mean can we connect a scrollBar signal to QTextEdit

Answer (score 0):

What you can do with `QTextEdit` is set its scrollbar though (I think you'd use `.setScrollBar()`).

Comment: Which of them connect(ui.textEdit,SIGNAL(..),..) or connect(ui.scrollBar,SIGNAL(..),..) write.